# Truffle Compile Error (Could not find zeppelin)

Tags: solidity, truffle

Truffle compile fails with error:

```
Error: Could not find zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken from any sources; imported from /home/mike/Desktop/test/contracts/TestCoin.sol
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:69147:23
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:165637:16
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:178009:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:69135:7
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:202146:5
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:177914:16
at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:165607:25)
at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:165597:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:165637:16
at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:202142:14)
```

There is blocks with imports:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken";
import "./TestCoin.sol";

contract TestCoinCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
```

Anybody knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ".sol" in the filename you want to import. It should be:

```
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken" fix to import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol";